# Configuring the number of config server retries on mongos start?

Tags: mongodb

I'm attempting to start `mongos` and fail fast if the config server is unavailable.  Right now, with an unavailable config server, I'm seeing:

`Tue Feb 12 11:09:13 [mongosMain] can't resolve DNS for [compute-1-3]  sleeping and trying 10 more times`

How do I configure the `10`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 10 retries is hard coded, it is not configurable.  You can see it here:

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/s/config.cpp#L742

Just in case line numbers change, here's the relevant counter/loop:

```
for ( int x=10; x>0; x-- ) {
                if ( ! hostbyname( host.c_str() ).empty() ) {
                    ok = true;
                    break;
                }
                log() << "can't resolve DNS for [" << host << "]  sleeping and trying " << x << " more times" << endl;
                sleepsecs( 10 );
```

Therefore you could, in theory, alter the code and re-build yourself, but then you would have to maintain that for new versions.  I would recommend instead that you keep the config server available instead, or at least have it up within ~100 seconds of the mongos starting.